# Unhandled Loop Exception in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, stack-overflow, gwt-designer

I'm getting an exception in Eclipse.
I am trying to create web application project using the GWT plugin. I have created a composite (name: Browser). After that I am trying to add browser composite in class (name: Home_Page) using `Choose Component` option.

When I add it give me error on design view:

> Exception during creation of browser. See error log for detail.

Please help me to rectify this problem.

```
public class Browse extends Composite {
    static HorizontalSplitPanel RepositoryDisplayPanel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();

public Browse() {
    //RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
            RepositoryDisplayPanel.setSplitPosition("200px");
            //rootPanel.add(RepositoryDisplayPanel);
            RepositoryDisplayPanel.setSize("762", "450");
            getObjectStoreTree();
            getObjectStoreCellTable();

}
public void getObjectStoreTree() {
    Tree repositories =new Tree();

    String repo[]={"ecm","ctmos","fhko","zert"};
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

        TreeItem reposiItem = new TreeItem();
        reposiItem.setText(repo[i]);
        reposiItem.setStyleName("cmis-TreeItem-objectstore");
        repositories.addItem(reposiItem);


    }
    RepositoryDisplayPanel.add(repositories);

}
public void getObjectStoreCellTable(){

    final CellTable<ContentofObjectStore> table = new CellTable<ContentofObjectStore>();
    table.setPageSize(3);

    // Create name Coloumn
    TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore> versionColumn = new TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore>() {
          @Override
          public String getValue(ContentofObjectStore object) {
            return object.version;
          }
        };


    TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore> nameColumn = new TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore>() {
          @Override
          public String getValue(ContentofObjectStore object) {
            return object.name;
          }
        };


    TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore> sizeColumn = new TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore>() {
          @Override
          public String getValue(ContentofObjectStore object) {
              return object.size;
           }
         };

    TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore> modified_byColumn = new TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore>() {
          @Override
          public String getValue(ContentofObjectStore object) {
              return object.modified_by;
          }
         };


         DateCell dateCell = new DateCell();
         Column<ContentofObjectStore, Date> dateColumn = new Column<ContentofObjectStore,Date>(dateCell){
             @Override
             public Date getValue(ContentofObjectStore object){
                 return object.modified_on;
             }

         };


    TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore> major_versionColumn = new TextColumn<ContentofObjectStore>() {
          @Override
          public String getValue(ContentofObjectStore object) {
              return object.major_version;
           }
         };
        // Add the columns.
         table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
         table.addColumn(versionColumn, "Version");
         table.addColumn(sizeColumn, "Size");
         table.addColumn(modified_byColumn, "Modified By");
         table.addColumn(dateColumn,"Modified On");
         table.addColumn(sizeColumn, "Major Version");

         RepositoryDisplayPanel.add(table);
         table.setHeight("188px");

}
```

}

in error log its says:

> unhandled loop exception "java.lang.StackOverflowError    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:2610)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4669)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4531)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:255)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2254)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3446)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:1977)  at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.updateControlsFromValue(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.access$1(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor$3.changed(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.semantics.AbstractValue.notifyListeners(AbstractValue.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.semantics.SimpleValue.setValue(SimpleValue.java:75)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor$1.modifyText(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:179)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:2610)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4669)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4531)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:255)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2254)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3446)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:1977)  at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.updateControlsFromValue(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.access$1(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor$3.changed(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.semantics.AbstractValue.notifyListeners(AbstractValue.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.semantics.SimpleValue.setValue(SimpleValue.java:75)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wb.internal.css.dialogs.style.AbstractTextButtonValueEditor$1.modifyText(AbstractTextButtonValueEditor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:179)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:2610)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4669)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4531)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:255)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2254)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3446)

Comment: it would be a good idea to see your code too... cause only looking the stacktrace is dificult to say what the problem is...

Comment: hi i have put the code. Plz check and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack overflow errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (the first line in your stack trace) don't have very many causes. The most likely scenario is that when you're adding the composite that you're somehow doing infinite recursion (that is, a method calling itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself...).

Look at the specs for whatever you're using and make sure you're adding the composite correctly. It could just be a typo somewhere, but it sounds like the issue is going to be near the insertion point.